# how can I make an href to an id appear like a whole different page (when clicked)?

Tags: html, css

I know that one type of link you can have is to a place within the page, using `<a href="#id_here">`.

I recently came across a [carrd website](https://neopronounss.carrd.co/), where clicking any of the links appears to take you to a new page, but I believe it's actually linking to an id (after clicking a link, you can see it's /#id rather than /someaddress). But it appears like a separate page, because you can't just scroll back up like usual when you use a link to an id.

I'm wondering how this works; I haven't been able to find anything on Google.

(edit: grammar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the site, click on the Who can use item in the menu on the 'front page' and have a look at the code through your browser's dev tools (not the source, the elements).

You'll see there are several sections looking like this sort of thing:

```
<section id="sources-section" class="inactive" style="display: none;">
```

but the one you clicked looks like this:

```
<section id="who-section" class="active" style="">
```

and in that section you'll see the text you can see on the screen.

Basically what they are doing is listening for clicks, and when they get one, use Javascript to set all sections to inactive class and display none style (I don't know why they need both) and set the one clicked to active class and remove the display none.

If you use your dev tools to unset the display none/inactive in another section you'll see that section's text displayed.

Answer (score 0):

They're listening for the navigation to the bookmark in JS. From there, they dynamically set the display value on the other section tags on the page. In other words, this is done with JS and isn't a normal function of the bookmarks feature. If you want to do this, you'd need to make a JS script that hides the rest of the page when you jump to a bookmark.